# How to add checkbox to first/welcome page in Inno Setup

Tags: checkbox, inno-setup, pascalscript

How do I add the check box to a particular page in Inno Setup?

I want the check box to be shown only in the first page or ReadyToInstall page?
I wrote code to add check box to `WizardForm`, but I see the check box is in every other page. I see we have to specify which page but i tried several options and it's just not happening.
I believe this should be simple but I'm totally lost.

Also, from the screenshot below, my checkbox label seems to have some highlighted background. how can i get rid of this background and add border to check box in light color?

[image]

```pascal
var
  EnableRMCheckBox: TNewCheckBox; 

procedure InitializeWizard;
  begin
    EnableRMCheckBox := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm);
    EnableRMCheckBox.Parent := WizardForm;
    EnableRMCheckBox.Top := 120;
    EnableRMCheckBox.Left := 87;
    EnableRMCheckBox.Width := 180;
    EnableRMCheckBox.Caption := 'Enable RM';  
  end;
```

Comment: The problem is the `Parent` that you chose. Use `WizardForm.WelcomePage` instead. Then the back color of the check box label will adapt to the page rather than the wizard form (`WizardForm` you used as `Parent`).

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

*Moving TLama's answer from comment to here.*

The problem is the `Parent` that you chose. Use `WizardForm.WelcomePage` instead. Then the back color of the check box label will adapt to the page rather than the wizard form (`WizardForm` you used as `Parent`).

Comment: The back color is just a side effect. The primary point of setting the `Parent` is that the checkbox is visible on the welcome page only, not everywhere.